# How to use machine learning or prediction to solve this regression in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression, prediction

I want to have a tip about machine learning.

Input:

```
[[2, 3, 7],
 [3, 9, 5],
 [2, 6, 4]]
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 1].T
```

are already given dataset. I want to know the output of Input [8, 1, 7]. I think it is a kind of machine learning - regression problem. Fundamentally, let's guess Input dataset is a group of pure numbers.

In long term, I want to know the case that some kinds of input sets are not pure number, but this is not urgent now, so I'll think it later. Intuitionally, it looks so simple, but I cannot search how to solve it because of my bad skill.

How can I tackle this?

Comment: In numpy, `[4, 1, 1].T` is `[4, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset of 3 observations is very small to employ a reasonable machine learning technique.
I'll probably go for k-nearest neighbours method here: given input, calculate the distance to known data points, and select the output associated with closest one.
Here, the closest observation (measured by Euclidian distance) to [8,1,7] is [2, 3, 7], so this method will predict that output is 4.
If you obtain larger dataset, you will be able to use much better methods.

Comment: Thank you my friend :) I had better make more datasets to ask something.